# Having trouble with segue

Tags: ios

please help!! tablecell is working fine for push to detailview without search bar but when i type a word on search bar, it appear correctly but it didn't push to detailview. 
appreciate for your help...

.h

```
@interface xtzViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate,UISearchDisplayDelegate>


{
IBOutlet UITableView *mytableview;
IBOutlet UISearchBar *SearchBar;
NSMutableArray *titleArray;
NSMutableArray *subtitleArray;
NSMutableArray *filteredString;
BOOL isFilltered;
}


@end
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

mytableview.delegate = self;
mytableview.dataSource = self;
SearchBar.delegate = self;

titleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"goat    ",@"cow   ",@"tiger",@"lion",@"elephant",nil];

subtitleArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"wX<w (rHR< cg)",@"o;vDRuwkR(vXw>csK;cHed;o;wkRtd.tCd)<*kRuhRto; (vXw>urXur.tylR)<o;vDRxl.",@"vhjbBGHvg",@"uNdD<",@"usdawYHgD",nil];


filteredString = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

}

-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
[mytableview resignFirstResponder];
}

-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
if(searchText.length == 0)
{
    isFilltered = NO;
}else
{
    isFilltered = YES;
    filteredString = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(NSString *str in titleArray)

    {
        NSRange stringRange = [str rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if(stringRange.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            [filteredString addObject:str];
        }
    }
}
[mytableview reloadData];
}

 -(NSInteger) numberOfSectionInTableView:(UITableView *)tableview
{

return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if(isFilltered)
{
    return [filteredString count];
}
else
{
return [titleArray count];
return [subtitleArray count];


}
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if(!cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

}
if(!isFilltered)
{
    cell.textLabel.text = [titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}else
{
    cell.textLabel.text = [filteredString objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
return cell;
}
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailSegue"])
{
    NSIndexPath *indexpath = nil;
    NSString    *titlestring = nil;
    NSString    *subtitlestring =nil;

    indexpath = [mytableview indexPathForSelectedRow];
    titlestring = [titleArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
    subtitlestring = [subtitleArray objectAtIndex: indexpath.row];

    [[segue destinationViewController] setTitlecontents:titlestring];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setSubtitlecontents:subtitlestring];

}
}
@end
```

Comment: [mytableview resignFirstResponder]; remove this line and try

Comment: You're using a search display controller? Make the segue a named one and trigger it from the table did select delegate method.